# TRIM the values from the middle of the string with MySql

Tags: sql, trim, domo

I have the data in domo platform, that I need to trim using sql. My data looks like the following:

```
id        Partner 
123       'HDM | R | Verizon (Tags)'
124       'JAM | R | T-Mobile (Tags)'
125       'EBDA - ALL | Aetna (Tags)'
126       'EBDA - HDR HMI | Aetna (Tags)'
```

I want the data looks like this:

```
id        Partner 
123       'Verizon (Tags)'
124       'T-Mobile (Tags)'
125       'EBDA Aetna (Tags)'
126       'EBDA Aetna (Tags)'
```

I have developed the logic that trimmed the first two values, but can't seem to figure out how to trim the values from the middle of the string: everything that is after EBDA and before the name of the company.

Here is my code:

```
select 
trim(TRIM(BOTH 'HDM | R |' FROM TRIM(BOTH 'JAM | R |' FROM TRIM(BOTH 'ALL | R |' FROM `Partner`)))) as `Partner`
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Sorry about that! I am using domo.

Comment: seeing this [link](https://knowledge.domo.com/Prepare/Magic_Transforms/SQL_DataFlows/01Creating_an_SQL_DataFlow) it is the same as MySQL

Comment: Correct, it is MySQL. Can't find any docs on how to trim from the middle of the string though, seems like trim method works for the beginning and the end of the string, where I need to exclude specific values...

Comment: You can use [INSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) and [SUBSTRING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr), biggest problem is the mixed separator '-' or '|'...)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, then use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(partner, ' | ', -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If **MySQL** then this is what you need:

```
select id
       , case when position(' - ' in Partner) > 0 then
            concat(substring_index(Partner, ' - ', 1) , ' ', substring_index(Partner, ' | ', -1))
            else substring_index(Partner, ' | ', -1)
         end Partner
from test
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e7ab0f18980efb6d10dd935cd234a370)